# How do I get the list of filtered (selectable) options in react-select based on the search input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) as more of an autocomplete search component.

For a select component with `<Select isSearchable={true}/>` react-select performs search autocomplete suggestions under the hood. It suggests selectable options as the user types and displays only those in the dropdown menu.

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a list of those suggested options as the input changes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be the case that you can. The closest access you have is to customize the filter logic, [see documentation](https://react-select.com/advanced#custom-filter-logic). Even this built in function only gets passed one option at a time, so in order to know all options that pass the filter, you'd need to aggregate the result elsewhere.

For me this would be needlessly complex for the problem at hand.

Filtering options, even if done twice, is typically not an expensive computation. The simplest solution would be to implement your own `onChange` that tracks the `value` of the `<Select />` then filters the options down, independent of the third party library.